# Array comparison of instances: returning unique elements of just the second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison, instance

## Technical Information

- 2 arrays
- both containing instances of one class
- The arrays can be of different lengths
- The class has a isSameAs() function

## Question

How can I compare the elements from these two arrays and return just the unique elements of the second array?

## Background

I want to crawl flats from the web and have a temporary array which will then be checked against the new crawled flats. Afterwards the temporary array becomes the just crawled flats array.
So if there are no new flats, the temporary array also can be empty.

## My approach

I first check, which array is longer. I then have a nested for loop beginning with the longer array to check each element against the shorter array. I am then stuck imagine all the possible conditions and don't know how to flag this.

```
function getJustUniqueElementsFromArray2(array1, array2){

  let uniqueElements = [];

  /* Checks which array is longer */
  let longerArray;
  let shorterArray;
  if (array2.length >= array1.length) {
    longerArray = array2;
    shorterArray = array1;
  } else {
    longerArray = array1;
    shorterArray = array2;
  }

  /* Nested for loop starting with longer array */
  for (let longerElem of longerArray) {
    for (let shorterElem of shorterArray) {

      //????
      if (!longerElem.isSameAs(shorterElem)) {
        uniqueElements.push(shorterElem);
      } else if (!shorterElem.isSameAs(longerElem)) {
        uniqueElements.push(longerElem);
      }
      //????

    }
  }

  return uniqueElements;

}
```

## Init Crawl

```
let tempFlats = [];
let newFlats = [A, B, C];
uniqueElements = [A, B, C];
tempFlats = newFlats;
```

## 2. Crawl

```
//now: tempFlats = [A, B, C];
newFlats = [A, B, C, D, E];
uniqueElements = [D, E];
tempFlats = newFlats;
```

## 3. Crawl

```
//now: tempFlats = [A, B, C, D, E];
newFlats = [A, E, F];
uniqueElements = [F];
tempFlats = newFlats;
```

## 4. Crawl

```
//now: tempFlats = [A, E, F];
newFlats = [A, B, G, H];
uniqueElements = [B, G, H];
tempFlats = newFlats;
```

## 5. Crawl

```
//now: tempFlats = [A, B, G, H];
newFlats = [];
uniqueElements = [];
tempFlats = newFlats;
```

## EDIT

I forgot to mention that the instances in the arrays are technically not the same.

```
tempFlats = [A1, B1, C1];
newFlats = [A2, B2, C2, D1, E1];

A1 == A2 // false
A1.isSameAs(A2) // true
```

## Solution

```
function getJustUniqueElementsFromArray2(array1, array2){

  let uniqueElements = [];

  /* Nested for loop starting with longer array */
  for (let elem2 of array2) {
    let found = false;

    for (let elem1 of array1) {
      if (elem2.isSameAs(elem1)) {
        found = true;
      }
    }

    if (!found) uniqueElements.push(elem2)
  }

  return uniqueElements;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array.

```js
function getUnique(left, right)  {
    var s = new Set(left);
    return right.filter(v => !s.has(v));
}
var tempFlats = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    newFlats = ['A', 'E', 'F'],
    uniqueElements = getUnique(tempFlats, newFlats);

console.log(uniqueElements);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just found a solution with the help of a friend.
Please see the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Even in that case, you can still get away with simple array methods.

```js
function getFlat(v) {
  return {
    val: v,
    isSameAs: function(o) {
      return this.val === o.val
    }
  }
}


var array1 = [getFlat(1), getFlat(2), getFlat(3)];
var array2 = [getFlat(2), getFlat(3), getFlat(9)];

function getJustUniqueElementsFromArray2(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.filter(x => arr1.filter(y => y.isSameAs(x)).length === 0);
}

console.log(getJustUniqueElementsFromArray2(array1, array2));
```

If you just need the unique elements from arr2 and working with primitives not refs:

```js
var arr1 = [3,5,67];
var arr2 = [43,5,167];

console.log(arr2.filter(x=> arr1.indexOf(x) === -1)) // print unique elements from arr2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just found a solution with the help of a friend.
Please see the edited post.